# Fetching APK from Google PlayStore through URL

Tags: android, url, google-play, apk

Is it programmatically possible to fetch an `APK` from the `Google PlayStore` just by entering the URL which one can get by visiting the `desktop version` of the `Google PlayStore` ? 

For example if the `URL` to the `APK` is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard

Does there lie any possible programmatic mean to `intake an URL` and `parse it` to fetch its `complimentary APK` ?